# Unable to create war file in Eclipse

Tags: java, war, webapp2

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/Jasmine/Documents/neo-billing-plugins-qao-sdp-facade.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.jee.archive.ArchiveSaveFailureException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver$UnderlyingFileNotFoundException: Cannot find the file C:\Users\Jasmine\.m2\repository\com\mindergy\mg\2.5.3\mg-2.5.3.jar in the file system. Make sure the file exists and try the operation again
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveArchive(FlatComponentArchiver.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver$UnderlyingFileNotFoundException: Cannot find the file C:\Users\Jasmine\.m2\repository\com\mindergy\mg\2.5.3\mg-2.5.3.jar in the file system. Make sure the file exists and try the operation again
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.addZipEntry(FlatComponentArchiver.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveFlatResources(FlatComponentArchiver.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveFlatResources(FlatComponentArchiver.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveFlatResources(FlatComponentArchiver.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.FlatComponentArchiver.saveArchive(FlatComponentArchiver.java:115)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is obvious:

> Cannot find the file C:\Users\Jasmine.m2\repository\com\mindergy\mg\2.5.3\mg-2.5.3.jar in the file system

But if you already use Maven, i would recommend to create the WAR file also with Maven. It will download and package all required dependencies. Just execute `mvn package` and you can find the WAR file in the output folder of the project (default it is `(project folder)/target`).

Answer (score 1):

Go to `properties>>library` then see `mg-2.5.3.jar`is broken as of now . so you have to build correct jar path then try it will work .

Comment: There is no mg-2.5.3.jar file I could find. The only .jar file is mg-2.4.0.jar

Comment: you Check on your Project Library whether any JAR file is broken or not . if it is broken means it doesn't fine the correct JAR file URL . then build correct jar path it will work . even you see on your logs file as well . where it is shown like mg-2.5.3.jar not find